# viewWithTag doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem with `viewWithTag`. I use this code for programmatically call a `UIViewController` from my storyboard. Then I want to set 2 imageView and I use viewWithTag.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
    BattleViewController *svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BattleViewController"];
    UIImageView*newImage=(UIImageView*)[svc.view viewWithTag:123];
    newImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1"];
    UIImageView*img2=(UIImageView*)[svc.view viewWithTag:234];
    img2.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"2"];

[self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

After this, the view controller is correctly called, but the two imageView are empty, there isn't anything on it.

Comment: you did set the tags in the BattleViewController in the storyboard, right?

Comment: Yes yes, in the storyboard I set the uiimageview with the same tag

Comment: and you are 100% sure that those images (1.png and 2.png) are in your main bundle, right?

Comment: Try creating `IBOutlet`s for those `UIImageView`s in your `BattleViewController` class, and connect them in your storyboard. Also, as matt suggests in his answer, you should be handling setting those images in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: As noted by Gavin, IBOutlets are a MUCH better way of handling this then trying to use tags anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is probably that you are doing this too early. When `svc` (your BattleViewController instance) is first created, it doesn't even have a view. Set things up so that you can hand the image file names to the view controller here, but let the view controller itself display the images in its own `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: You're right that he should handle this in `viewDidLoad`, but but that's not his problem, because as soon as he calls `svc.view`, it will cause the view to be loaded.

Comment: @Gavin agreed, that's why I said "probably" :)

Answer (score 0):

What kind of view is BattleViewController?
Is this a tableview? Is it another type of view?
Your view from the tag might be in a subview of BattleViewController.

Try this:

```
NSLog(@"subviews = %@", svc.view.subviews)
```

This will output the total number of views you have in svc. If you have more than one subview, your image with tag might be under one of these subviews (so then you do:

```
UIImageView*newImage=(UIImageView*)[[svc.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1] viewWithTag:123]];
```